# JMeter jdbc:mysql error

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter, mysql-connector

I am trying to setup a `JMeter` server/client instance on a remote database server. I have extracted `JMeter` on the server, copied the MySQL java connector into $JMETER_HOME/lib and started the `JMeter`-server listener. On the client (my local desktop), I have pointed the `JMeter`client to the remote server (via the remote_hosts entry in $JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.properties). Whenever I try to run a MySQL load job on the client (Run -> Remote Start -> ), I get the following error:

> Response message: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4/database

And this is on the server side:

> 2013/04/10 12:44:43 WARN - jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement: Could not return Connection java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4/dbname at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.JdbcConnectionFactory.newInstance(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:185) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(ResourceLimitingPool.java:672) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:178) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.newPoolable(ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.java:123) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ResourceLimitingPool.get(ResourceLimitingPool.java:402) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.get(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:130) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.getConnection(ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.java:222) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:286) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:146) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:85) at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428) at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Does anyone have any idea why this wouldn't work even though the Java connector is in the jmeter lib dir?

Comment: Also, thanks to the person who downvoted but didn't provide any comments at all, positive, negative, or otherwise.

Comment: Is it also in the lib dir of the client?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Yes, the jar is also in the lib dir of the client. Also checked perms on bother server and client side so the match the rest of the jars in the lib dir.

Comment: you have cross posted this ques on servar fault and SO. This should not be done !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that the Percona MySQL version that we are running required a specific version of the connector.  Dropped that in and it all worked out.

Comment: i have mysql 5.6.19b running amazon rds (remote db, for simplicity) and my connector's version is 5.1.22 , is it compatibel ?